# Create a cross-platform protocol helper that runs a python script

Tags: python, url, cross-platform

I'd like to register a protocol handler, like `"myapp:"`, across OS `X`, `Linux`, and `Windows` so that when someone clicks an `URL` like `"myapp://some/params"` in a web browser, a Python script will be called and passed in those params.

Obviously, this would require something being installed on each machine to enable it, but just try to figure out a way to make it work on all three platforms.

Comment: Have you found a way of doing this? I posted pretty much a duplicate question.

Comment: My question is phrased marginally differently and can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19401424/cross-platform-custom-protocol-handler-tool