# Cross-platform custom protocol handler tool

Tags: cross-platform, protocols, handler

I'd like my application to be opened whenever a URL of the form

`appname://some/url/here`

is opened on Windows, Mac OSX and Ubuntu Linux.

There are of course [platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471581/how-to-map-a-custom-protocol-to-an-application-on-the-mac) [specific](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418910/osx-defining-a-new-url-handler-that-points-straight-at-a-python-script) [ways](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6965/system-wide-browser-protocol-handlers) to achieve this but is there a single (say, Python) tool that would accomplish this with minimal fuss?

Comment: I'm particularly interested in solutions on the Mac. I have managed to [this gist](https://gist.github.com/miketaylr/5969656), which details how setting the protocol can be accomplished with PyObjC; this can be a challenge when packaging for deployment. Could there be other ways to do this?